# Django: changing OneToOneField to ForeignKey ends up with 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-one

Already tried using a Proxy model to access the `User` model from `django-authtools` package, but it still shows the same error. I do admit that I may have been doing this wrong, so feel free to suggest anything and I will try it. Thanks!

The model I use is from the `django-authtools` package.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authtools.User'
```

This is from my `models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile')
```

I've been working on this project for quite a while and have used multiple of the lines below**:

```
user.profile
user.profile.name
user.profile.playlists
# and many others
```

Now for my use case, I realized I needed to have multiple Profiles for one login so I was planning to go from `OneToOneField` to `ForeignKey`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profiles')
```

** With this, my previous codes need to be changed because I won't be able to call the old `profile` attributes freely because it will be returning a set, not a single instance.

Instead, I want to do something like the following:

```
user.profile = user.profiles.all().first()
```

so that I don't have to change all the lines with `user.profile`. But I don't know where I can declare this and I badly need help because it's turning into a major blocker.

Any ideas? Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the property method in the use model.

```
@property
def profile(self):
    retrun self.profiles.first()
```

Comment: I already did this, even through a Proxy model but it doesn't work. I can't directly access the User model because it is from the django-authtools package. If you know how to override it, then please share your methods.

Comment: You can try the monkey patch method, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If model is not define by you, you can try monkey patch

```
from module import ClassToPatch

def get_profile(self):
     retrun self.profiles.first() 

ClassToPatch.profile = property(get_profile)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I need.